# Tautology verification algorithm

Tags: algorithm, np-complete

Is there a better algorithm for `tautology verification` for more than 2 propositional variables.

`Brute force` will take O(2^n) for validating against all possible truth values.

Comment: Use a complete SAT solver.

Comment: Tried different methods like shunting yard algorithm to solve this.  Didn't get any working algorithm except brute force. I can not use any script engines also. Do we have any known algorithm in this regard.

Comment: (You really should do a little research before asking a question here.) According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Efficient_verification_and_the_Boolean_satisfiability_problem, the problem is known to be NP-complete, and it is "widely believed that there is no polynomial-time algorithm that can perform it." It's an active area of research in automated theorem proving.